# Using atan2 with a class template fails with ambigous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to use the function `atan2` in my class template but it's not working. I've got a class called myclass and I'm trying make a template of the functions, this function is to take the tan of two numbers, a and b. These could either both be int or both be doubles

```
template <class T>   
T myclass<T>::returnArg()  
{  
    T arg(0);  
    arg = atan2(a, b);  
    return arg;  
}
```

But I get `error C2668: 'atan2' : ambiguous call to overloaded function`. Can anyone suggest something to fix this?

Thank you.

Edit: I would like to be able to pass ints and doubles to the atan2 function, I have tried

```
arg = atan2(<T> a, <T> b);
```

But that didn't work.

Edit 2: I declare a and b in my class as

```
template <class T> class myclass
{
private:
    T a,b;
public:
    myclass(): a(0),b(0){};
    myclass(T r, T i) : a(r), b(i){};
// ...
```

Comment: Are `a` and `b` globals?

Comment: A hint: if the error message mentions an "overloaded function", the types of the function parameters are vital to the question.

Comment: @ildjarn I want a and b to be able to be int or double type

Comment: I didn't ask what types you want them to be, I asked what types they actually _are_ when you receive this error.

Comment: They are both int and double, I use the function with integer and double class instances

Comment: @Gar Can you show how you declare a and b in the `myclass` definition?

Comment: @Prætorian done, hope that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ defines several overloads for [`atan2`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) depending on the types of its input arguments. If `a` and `b` in your code snippet are different types, then overload resolution will fail since the call is ambiguous.

You need to cast `a` or `b` as appropriate so that their types match.

If you intended to call `atan2(double, double)`, an alternate solution would be to include `math.h` instead of `cmath` and then call the function as `::atan2( a, b )`. This will implicitly convert both `a` and `b` to `double` (if such a conversion is possible).